# SQLCODE: -413\n- conversion error from string?

Tags: python, sql, firebird

Делаю запрос к базе с явным приведением к типу, но получаю ошибку. Типы полей `VARCHAR` и `DATE`

```
sqlquery = """SELECT CAST(BOOK1.R001F AS CHAR(30)), CAST(CAR_A103.R1024 AS CHAR(10)) \
          FROM BOOK1 LEFT OUTER JOIN CAR_A103 \
          ON BOOK1.R001F = CAR_A103.R1024"""

connect = fdb.connect(dsn='C:\c.gdb', user='sysdba', password='master')
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlquery)
result= cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

Ошибка:

```
  raise exception_from_status(DatabaseError, self._isc_status, "Cursor.fetchone:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Cursor.fetchone:\n- SQLCODE: -413\n- conversion error from string "пин"', -413, 335544334)
```

Comment: Приведение типа надо делать в ON clause! Причём к одному и тому же типу.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina Всё верно спасибо, заработало, поставьте в ответ. А можно ускорить выполнение этого запроса если он обращается к базе со 100 000 записями?

Comment: 1) Я не стану писать ответ "втёмную". Если бы Вы выполнили требования по оформлению вопроса - другое дело. А в нынешнем виде такой ответ бесполезен. 2) Ускорить можно созданием подходящих индексов. Но Firebird не поддерживает индекс по выражению емнип - так что я бы рекомендовал привести типы данных к одному знаменателю и проиндексировать поля.